# React two depths cascading menu that opens on mouse over not closing when mouse leaves the buttton

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, menu, cascadingdropdown

I am building 2 depths cascading menu that opens when I hover an element.
I've made it work so that when I hover the `SHOP` button, the first depth of the menu opens, and when I hover the mouse on each menu item, the second menu opens.

The problem is that the menu remains open when my mouse is on the menu as I expected, but when I hover the mouse on the shop button and then move the cursor to the other outside area, it does not close. It closes after I first move the cursor to the menu.

Here is the expected behavior:

1. The main category menu opens when I hover the mouse on the shop button.
2. Sub Category menu opens when I hover the mouse on the shop button.
3. When I move the cursor to the area that is neither shop button nor menu, the whole menu closes.

Please help me!! Thank you.
[Link to the CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-shamir-wyi0j7?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

This way you can achieve expected result

```
<Button
    value={isOpen}
    onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnterShop}
    onMouseLeave={(e) => {
      if (e.relatedTarget === categoryRef.current) return;
      handleMouseLeaveShop();
    }}
  >
    SHOP
</Button>
```

And minor change in style

```
const CategoryMenu = styled.div`
display: ${({ isOpen }) => (isOpen ? "block" : "none")};
 position: absolute;
 background: #fff;
 width: 200px;
 margin-top: -5px;
 min-height: 500px;
 padding: 25px;
 box-shadow: 8px 5px 8px 1px rgb(0 10 18 / 10%), 0 0 0 1px rgb(0 10 18 / 10%);
 transform: translateY(4px);
`;
```

Hope this will solve!

Comment: Thank you so much! I was using useEffect and added event listener, but your solution is so much simple. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @YoungjunWoo You most welcome.
Please upvote and tick my solution.